# Why getting blur image captured from camera in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

1. I have captured an image from the camera, but image getting blur in
   onActivityResult. below is my code, what could be the reason behind the blur image?

   ```
   if(requestCode==
             Constants.PermissionRequestCodes.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA
            {
              if (data != null) {
               if (!data.toString().equals("Intent {  }")) {
                   val thumbnail = data!!.extras!!.get("data")
                   val contentURI = 
                     MediaHelper.getImageUri(this,thumbnail as   Bitmap)
                   opnCropImageActivity(contentURI, 
                       requestCode,thumbnail as Bitmap)
               }
            }
      } 
   fun getImageUri(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {
               val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
               inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
               val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.contentResolver,
   inImage, "Title", null)
               return Uri.parse(path)
           }
   ```